# wikitude invalid key on android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude

I have some trouble with wikitude and android, when I lunch wikitude sometimes i get the watermarks with invalid key message, I requested the API on wikitude site and I create a new WikitudeARIntent in this way

```
WikitudeARIntent ARintent = new WikitudeARIntent(this.getApplication(), "my app name", "59393c83-13a5-4fa3-bbc8-bee404abe50f", "my name");
```

Where "my app name" is the app name indicated in the registration form on wikitude site, same thing for "my name" is the dev name.
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i didnt write the application name and it runs fine. Try omitting the application name

Answer (score 0):

```
WikitudeARIntent intent = new WikitudeARIntent(this.getApplication(), this.getString(R.string.api_key), this.getString(R.string.developer_name));
```

as noted above, try removing the application name attribute